# How can I remove x number of zeros from the beginning of a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, binary, numeric-data

So I made a decimal to binary converter but currently it doesn't chop off the zeros in the beginning. If I entered 64 for $1 it would start with 13 zeros which is rather unsightly but I don't know how to chop them off. Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/null > ~/Documents/.tobinary
touch ~/Documents/.tobinary

toBin=$1
counter=0
numZeros=0
first1=0
kill=0
echo $toBin

for v in {19..0}
do
    let temp=2**$v
    let test=$toBin-$temp

    if [ $test -ge 0 ]
    then
            if [ $first1 -eq 0 ]
            then
                    kill=$numZeros
                    let first1++
            fi
            if [ $test -gt 0 ]
            then
                    echo -n 1 >> ~/Documents/.tobinary
                    toBin=$test
            elif [ $test -eq 0 ]
            then
                    echo -n 1 >> ~/Documents/.tobinary
                    while [ $counter -lt $v ]
                    do
                        echo -n 0 >> ~/Documents/.tobinary
                            let counter++
                    done
                    break
            fi
    elif [ $test -lt 0 ]
    then
            echo -n 0 >> ~/Documents/.tobinary
            let numZeros++
    fi
done

cat ~/Documents/.tobinary
```

Comment: Is there a strong reason against using `bc` (with obase=2)?

Comment: This look like self training purpose, you can "see" all execution using `set -x` in first line, you might whish to reduce wideness (e.g. {5-0} instead of {19-0}). Real unixan do use `echo` and `set -x` when debugging.

Comment: `sed '1s/^0*//' file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason for which you used this particular algorithm?

I'd rather construct the binary in shell variables than in a file. In such case you can strip the leading zeroes by adding a zero to a number, such as

```
expr 00001111 + 0
1111
```

Also, if you have to use a file, I would suggest using /tmp instead of ~/Documents to hold temporary files. And finally, if I were you, I would prefer to construct the binary using a divide method, which naturally ends when the conversion is completed, thus avoiding the problem of leading zeroes rather than solving it.

Comment: How would I construct the binary in a shell variable. As a string? Would I replace the 'echo -n 1 >> ~/Documents/.tobinary' with 'answer="$answer"+"1"'?